# Writing python web scraped data to .csv file on a Mac

Tags: python

I am brand new to Python and taking a class. I think I am close to completing the requirements but am stuck on getting my data into a csv file.   The file is always empty.   I have tried multiple things with the write portion of the code and still can't figure it out. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os.path

url = "https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html"
response = requests.get(url)
# parse html
page = str(BeautifulSoup(response.content))

def getURL(page):
    start_link = page.find("a href")
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1: end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

while True:
    url, n = getURL(page)
    page = page[n:]
    if url:
        print url
    else:
        break

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
myfile = os.path.join(userhome, 'Desktop', 'data.csv')

f=open(myfile,"w")
f.write(getURL)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I already see is that you're not calling `getUrl`

`f.write(getUrl(page)[0])`

Also you're trying to write to the file later when the the data is lost.

The `while` loop finds all the urls in the page you're scraping so you will need to write the file in that loop.

```
userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
myfile = os.path.join(userhome, 'Desktop', 'data.csv')

with open(myfile, "w") as f:
    while True:
        url, n = getURL(page)
        page = page[n:]
        if url:
            print(url)
            f.write("%s\n" % getURL(page)[0])
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Thank you all for your wonderful suggestions.  All worked great and helped me understand where I was making my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

`f.write()` expects a `str` and you give it a function (`getURL`).
You must give it a string.
`f.write(getUrl()[0])` should work if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Python 2 or 3? I noticed you're calling the print function without parentheses.

Your main issue is that you're only calling the function (getURL) to f.write, you need to pass the actual values you're trying to save. In your case, the "url" variable you're printing is what I assume you're trying to save.

Although I'm not exactly sure this is the format you want, in my data.csv file I have every URL on a new line by making these changes:

1. Move this code to lines *before* your while loop:

userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')

myfile = os.path.join(userhome, 'Desktop', 'data.csv')

f=open(myfile,"w")

2. In your while loop, add this immediately before of after your print statement:

   f.write(url+"\n")
3. leave f.close() at the end of your script